# e.Item.Text returning the text of another menuitem

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a menu in ASP.NET which looks like the image below:

[image: vertical hierachical menu]

I have created that menu dynamically. Here is the C# code:

```
private void GetMenuItems()
{
    string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("spGetMenuData", con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);

    foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        if (dr["ParentID"].ToString().Trim() == "")
        {
            MenuItem item = new MenuItem();
            item.Text = dr["MenuItemName"].ToString();
            //item.NavigateUrl = dr["NavigateUrl"].ToString();
            item.Value = dr["NavigateUrl"].ToString();
            //item.ToolTip = dr["MenuItemID"].ToString();

            foreach (DataRow drChild in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                if (drChild["ParentID"].ToString() == dr["MenuItemID"].ToString())
                {
                    GetChildItems(ds, drChild, item);
                }
            }

            Menu1.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }
}

private static void GetChildItems(DataSet ds, DataRow dr, MenuItem item)
{
    MenuItem childItem = new MenuItem();
    childItem.Text = dr["MenuItemName"].ToString();
    //childItem.NavigateUrl = dr["NavigateUrl"].ToString();
    childItem.Value = dr["NavigateUrl"].ToString();
    //childItem.ToolTip = dr["MenuItemID"].ToString();

    foreach (DataRow drChild in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        if (drChild["ParentID"].ToString() == dr["MenuItemID"].ToString())
        {
            GetChildItems(ds, drChild, childItem);
        }
    }

    item.ChildItems.Add(childItem);
}
```

I call the above `GetMenuItems()` method in the `Page_Load` event with `IsPostBack = false`.

Now I have OnMenuItemClick as follows:

```
protected void Menu1_MenuItemClick(object sender, MenuEventArgs e)
{
    Session["SelectedMenuItemName"] = e.Item.Text;
    Response.Redirect(e.Item.Value);
}
```

Now, suppose I click the mouse as shown in the image above, when I check `e.Item.Text`, I get "Laptop" which is the first item on that same level. In a similar fashion if I select any Item under Electronics, I get `e.Item.Text = "Laptop"`. I have also tried `Menu1.SelectedItem.Text` but still I get the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem MenuItem's Value Property.

I mean don't store your NavigateUrl in MenuItem's Value Property.

And then just try to run your project and I am sure that you will get the desired value in `e.Item.Text`.

Still if you have any problems then feel free to comment here.

Thanks.